# agregar elementos drag and drop a input con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo este ejemplo de drag and drop pero solo se puede agregar un solo elemento al input, despues si quiero agregar otro ya no lo agrega 
¿Como puedo hacer para que me deje agregar mas elementos al input?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#reset').on('click', function(){
    $('ul').attr('id', 'draggable');
    //$('.p_lang').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.p_lang').val('');
   });
  $('li').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  });
  $( "#draggable li" ).draggable({helper: 'clone'});
  $(".p_lang").droppable({
   accept: "#draggable li",
   drop: function(ev, ui) {
   $(this).insertAtCaret(ui.draggable.text());
   //$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   $("#draggable").removeAttr('id');
   }
  });
  });
  
  $.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
  return this.each(function(){
  if (document.selection) {
    this.focus();
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = myValue;
    this.focus();
  }
  
  else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
    var startPos = this.selectionStart;
    var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
    this.focus();
    this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
    this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
    this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  } else {
    this.value += myValue;
    this.focus();
  }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class = "row">
 <div class  = "col-md-3"></div>
 <div class  = "col-md-6 well">
  <h3 class = "text-primary">Drag and drop inserting text to input text box with jQuery</h3>
  <hr style = "border-top: 1px dotted #8c8b8b;"/>
   <div class = "pull-left" style = "border:1px #000 dotted; width:230px;">
   <center><label style = "font-size:9px;" class = "alert-danger">Please drag your favorite programming language</label></center>
    <ul  style = "list-style-type:none;" id = "draggable">
     <li>PHP</li>
     <li>Javascript</li>
     <li>Java</li>
     <li>HTML</li>
     <li>C</li>
     <li>C++</li>
     <li>C#</li>
     <li>Python</li>
     <li>Vb.net</li>
     <li>Ruby</li>
     <li>Pearl</li>
    </ul>
    <p></p>
   </div>
   <div class = "pull-right" style = "padding:20px; border:1px #000 dotted; width:400px;">
    <div class = "form-group">
     <input type = "text" name = "program" class = "form-control p_lang ui-droppable" />
     <center><label>Your favorite language</label></center>
     <button class = "btn btn-success pull-left" id = "reset" type = "button"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Reset</button>
    </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en tu lógica de código, al momento de ejecutar el método `drop` estás removiendo el `id #draggable`: `$("#draggable").removeAttr('id');` al hacer esto los elementos `li` que pertenecen a dicho elemento ya no son reconocidos como `draggables` `$( "#draggable li" ).draggable({helper: 'clone'});`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#reset').on('click', function(){
    $('ul').attr('id', 'draggable');
    //$('.p_lang').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.p_lang').val('');
   });
    
  $('li').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  });
    
  $( "#draggable li" ).draggable({helper: 'clone'});
    
  $(".p_lang").droppable({
   accept: "#draggable li",
   drop: function(ev, ui) {
   $(this).insertAtCaret(ui.draggable.text());
   //$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   //$("#draggable").removeAttr('id');
   }
  });
  });
  
  $.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
  return this.each(function(){
  if (document.selection) {
    this.focus();
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = myValue;
    this.focus();
  }else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
    var startPos = this.selectionStart;
    var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
    this.focus();
    this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
    this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
    this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  } else {
    this.value += myValue;
    this.focus();
  }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class = "row">
 <div class  = "col-md-3"></div>
 <div class  = "col-md-6 well">
  <h3 class = "text-primary">Drag and drop inserting text to input text box with jQuery</h3>
  <hr style = "border-top: 1px dotted #8c8b8b;"/>
   <div class = "pull-left" style = "border:1px #000 dotted; width:230px;">
   <center><label style = "font-size:9px;" class = "alert-danger">Please drag your favorite programming language</label></center>
    <ul  style = "list-style-type:none;" id = "draggable">
     <li>PHP</li>
     <li>Javascript</li>
     <li>Java</li>
     <li>HTML</li>
     <li>C</li>
     <li>C++</li>
     <li>C#</li>
     <li>Python</li>
     <li>Vb.net</li>
     <li>Ruby</li>
     <li>Pearl</li>
    </ul>
    <p></p>
   </div>
   <div class = "pull-right" style = "padding:20px; border:1px #000 dotted; width:400px;">
    <div class = "form-group">
     <input type = "text" name = "program" class = "form-control p_lang ui-droppable" />
     <center><label>Your favorite language</label></center>
     <button class = "btn btn-success pull-left" id = "reset" type = "button"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Reset</button>
    </div>
   </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```